# Do templates need overloaded constructors?

Tags: c++, templates

I just finished watching some videos of template and I think I am missing some concepts. Why doesn't the constructor get called, or why the object is not created when the constructor is not overloaded with a desired data-type? Since I am writing the `<int>` doesn't the compiler know I am going to be dealing with an int?

```
template <class T>
class Generic {
    T var;
public:
    Generic(){cout << "ctor called " << endl;}
    //Generic (T v) {var = v;}
};


int main () {

    Generic<int> generic1();

}
```

Can't I create an object like this and then modify the value of T var through a setter? Why should I need an overloaded constructor e.g.  `Generic<int> generic1(9);` ?

Comment: Why do two operation when you could do one?

Comment: Most vexing parse.

Comment: Lookup "the most vexing parse". You need to use `Generic<int> generic1;`

Comment: @vsoftco I don't think that dupe is right.  I believe the OP asking why they should provide a constructor that takes a value when they could just write a setter.

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right, reopened. I just saw it on the first line of main :) But it's a combination of both.

Comment: Actually it looks like it might be both.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It was my mistake, I had extra '()' while creating an object with no params.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) issue.

Of course you can initialize the object via the default constructor, and modify the value via a setter later, the problem here is that you're not defining a variable. `Generic<int> generic1();` is a declaration of function, which is named `generic1`, takes no arguments and returns `Generic<int>`.

What you want is

```
Generic<int> generic1;
```

or

```
Generic<int> generic1{}; // since C++11
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My mistake I didn't see that.